# Validation in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations

I have some problems with validation using Data Annotations in ASP.NET MVC 2. For example, I have Address class:

```
public class Address
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

And Order class:

```
public class Order
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public Address FirstAddress { get; set; }

    public Address SecondAddress { get; set; }

    public bool RequireSecondAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I want to validate Order.FirstAddress all the time, but Order.SecondAddress should be validated only if Order.RequireSecondAddress is set to true.

Any ideas? :)

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's close to impossible using data annotations or it will require writing ugly code that relies on reflection, etc... (I think you get the point).

I would recommend you looking at the [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). It has a good [integration with ASP.NET MVC](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2009/05/11/fluent-validation-model-binder-aspnet-mvc/). Here's how your validation logic might look like:

```
public class AddressValidator : AbstractValidator<Address>
{
    public AddressValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.City)
            .NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.PostalCode)
            .NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Street)
            .NotEmpty();
    }
}

public class OrderValidator : AbstractValidator<Order>
{
    public OrderValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.FirstAddress)
            .SetValidator(new AddressValidator());
        RuleFor(x => x.SecondAddress)
            .SetValidator(new AddressValidator())
            .When(x => x.RequireSecondAddress);
    }
}
```

You will also benefit from having a separate validation layer which also could be [unit tested in a very elegant way](http://richarddingwall.name/2009/08/19/asp-net-mvc-tdd-and-fluent-validation/).

Comment: In FluentValidator there are some problems in the client-side with more complex validations, but I think this is not a big issue. Now I'm going to learn more about FluentValidator :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following conditional validation articles might help:

- [Conditional Validation in MVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/04/conditional-validation-in-mvc.aspx)
- [Adding Client-Side Script to an MVC Conditional Validator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/11/adding-client-side-script-to-an-mvc-conditional-validator.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I've been looking for.